# How do I register a custom peewee field as a postgres money type

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, peewee

I'm trying to connect to a PSQL table with peewee that has a "money" columnQL named "price". Every time I connect and save an object, the price column remains blank but the other fields are saved just fine. What am I doing wrong here?

I'm using PostgresSQL 10.5 and Peewee 3.9.3

````
from peewee import *


# Just returning the actual value for now. Do I just need to convert?
class CurrencyField(DoubleField):
    def db_value(self, value):
        return super().db_value(value)

    def python_value(self, value):
        return super().python_value(value)


db = PostgresqlDatabase('testdb', user='guest', field_types={CurrencyField: 'MONEY'})


class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db


class User(BaseModel):
    username = CharField()


class Product(BaseModel):
    price = CurrencyField
    name = CharField(max_length=355)```
````

Answer (score 0):

First of all your method overrides do nothing so get rid of them. Then add the field type as it is used in postgres:

```
class CurrencyField(DoubleField):
   field_type = 'MONEY'
```

Then in your model, you are not instantiating the field (no parentheses after the field). You need to use a field instance...not the class.

```
class Product(BaseModel):
    price = CurrencyField()  # ADD PARENS
    name = CharField(max_length=355)
```

You don't need to register anything. The above code is all you need.